# raster / tiff ImageMagick Error

Tags: r, imagemagick, tiff, raster

I am trying to feed Imagemagick a stack of rasters but have been unsuccessful. I've read that I might need to convert to jpeg or png first, but this too fails. Here is an example:

```
library(magick)
r1 <- raster(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10))
image_read(r1)
```

I get: "Error in image_read(r1) : path must be URL, filename or raw vector"

```
writeRaster(r1,"/Desktop/raster_tmp/r1.tif",overwrite=TRUE)
image_read("/Desktop/raster_tmp/r1.tif")
```

I get: "Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth) : 
  Magick: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/910"

```
image_convert(r1,"png")
```

"Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object."

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It's common to have tiff warnings when reading meta-tags. Optional/private tags may be added by various vendors or extended by third-part libraries. [GDAL](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/gdal_nodata.html) in your example. Might be worth inquiring with R magick's maintainer(s) to see why a _warning_ is being treated as an _error_.

Comment: Hah! Thanks, this rather basic function for ImageMagick renders an actual error, not a warning being treated as an error. Must be bugs in this early version for R.